# Divisibility in a recurrent sequence

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a_1=0$, $a_2=\alpha$, and $a_n=\lambda a_{n-1}+\mu a_{n-2}$ for $n\geq 3$.

Are there positive integers $\alpha$, $\lambda$, $\mu$ such that 
$$a_{p^2} \equiv 0 \mod p $$
for every prime $p>2$?

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can explicitly compute $a_{p^2}$ modulo $p$ using the binomial theorem.  The equation you give can only hold for primes dividing $\lambda^2+4\mu$ (or $\alpha$).

For example, in the Fibonacci sequence the prime $5$ has period $5$, but every other prime $p$ has period dividing $p^2-1$ (hence not dividing $p^2$).

Answer (score 0):

little hint :

$$ a_n - \lambda a_{n-1} - \mu a_{n-2} = 0 $$

$$ m^2 - \lambda m - \mu = 0 \Rightarrow m_{1,2} = \frac{\lambda \pm \sqrt{\lambda^2  + 4\mu}}{2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow a_n = c_1 \left(  \frac{\lambda + \sqrt{\lambda^2  + 4\mu}}{2} \right)^n + c_2 \left(  \frac{\lambda - \sqrt{\lambda^2  + 4\mu}}{2} \right)^n $$

$$ a_1 = 0 , a_2 = \alpha \Rightarrow a_n = ??? $$